# Want to compare value at one geographic location to another location

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with columns for latitude, longitude, hwmQualityName, elevation, description, and other non-essential information. Shown below is the dataframe for only latitude, longitude, hwmQualityName, elevation, and description. There are additional columns with values in the dataframe before the latitude column, after the description column, and in between the latitude, longitude, hwmQualityName, elev_ft, and hwm_locationdescription columns:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import netCDF4 as nc4
import os
import sys
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly.offline as po
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import pathlib as pl
import matplotlib as mpl
import pandas as pd
import sys;sys.path.append('../ncsurge')
from importlib import reload
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiPoint
from shapely.ops import nearest_points
from hwm import *

root_hwm = pl.Path(r'P:\Temp\bpozo\Scripts\HWM')
A = pd.read_csv(str(root_hwm / 'FilteredHWMs.csv'))
hwm_m = gpd.GeoDataFrame(A)
hwm_m

latitude       longitude        hwmQualityName           elev_ft     hwm_locationdescription
35.281050926   -76.6625853795   'Excellent: +/- 0.05 ft'  7.288     'side of left garage'
34.676933      -77.080633       'Poor: +/- 0.40 ft'      12.241     'outside marked with pen'
...
34.94107586    -76.6507665736   'Good: +/- 0.10 ft'       6.025     'side of post'
```

There a certain number of these points (say 100) that are located along the coastline and are relatively near each other when seen on a map. What I want to do are a couple things:

1) I want to compare the elev_ft value at each location to the elev_ft values in  surrounding locations given a radius of say 300 ft to determine if the elev_ft value at the location I am looking at is an outlier.

2) After identifying the locations that have an elev_ft value that is an outlier, I want to use the strings in the hwmQualityName column and the hwm_locationdescription column to remove all points (i.e. remove the entire row from the dataframe) that contain the word "Poor" in the hwmQualityName column or that contain the word "waves" or any additional words related to waves in the hwm_locationdescription column.

What I hope to have in the end is a dataframe that has removed points based on the conditions described above.

I am new to Python and I don't know the best way to tackle this task.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: are the latitudes and longitudes ordered to be along the coast, or could say position1 be at the top, position2 at the bottom, and position3 at the top again?

Comment: It would be the latter. The way the latitudes and longitudes for each corresponding point are organized in the dataframe is that they are random non-ordered geographical points. For example (without looking into the exact locations), the 1st point in the dataframe could be located at a more northern location relative to the 2nd point in the dataframe, but the 3rd point in the dataframe could be located north of the 2nd point but south of the 1st point and not necessarily south of both the 1st and 2nd dataframe points.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a distance function would be useful for part 1). Here is one that I made/found most of online:

```
def calculate_distance(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2):
    import math
    latitude1 = math.radians(latitude1)
    longitude1 = math.radians(longitude1)
    latitude2 = math.radians(latitude2)
    longitude2 = math.radians(longitude2)
    delta_lon = abs(longitude1 - longitude2)
    delta_lat = abs(latitude1 - latitude2)
    term1 = math.sin(delta_lat / 2) ** 2
    term2 = math.cos(latitude1) * math.cos(latitude2) * math.sin(delta_lon / 2) ** 2
    a = term1 + term2
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
    distance = c * 6378100 # c * radius of Earth in meters
    return distance
```

You could use this function to determine the "300 ft" part of it. I should note this returns the distance in meters, and I'm not sure of the accuracy. I believe when I tested it the function was like 99.8% accurate, but if you're measuring down to the foot that may not be accurate enough

To credit where I found the math: https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 0):

You have coordinates and you want to give a radius in feet. You will make things a lot easier on your self if you convert feet to your coordinates unit of measure, longitude and latitude is usually in degrees, minutes and seconds and 1 second is approx 90 ft. 300ft = 3.3 seconds = 0.055 minutes = .00092 degress. I rounded the numbers because it would appear you don't need to be super precise on the distance, but it still should be accurate down to <10 feet.

Then the math for figuring out if one coordinate is within range of another can be found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681236/calculate-whether-one-coordinate-is-within-range-of-another)